# attr is not a function in jquery

Tags: jquery

Below is my jQuery Code, I have to change the attribute:

**I have 2 list of similar items, i have to disable selected item of first in second list, and in first list i have prefix lstrYM with Item and in second list having prefix ltrY2 with item**

I am very week in jquery , so  i dont know how exact find, so i am runnig the loop

```
 $('#lsltrYMaxis').change(function () {
     var flg = 0;
     $('#lsltrYMaxis option').each(function () {
         var val = this.value;
         val = val.replace("YMa", "Y2a"); // find y2 axis with similar index
         var chk = $(this).is(':checked'); // checked 
         //            alert(val);
         //            alert(chk);
         $('#lsltrY2axis option').each(function () {
            var val2 = this.value;
            alert(val + ";" + val2 + ";" + chk);
            if (val === val2) {
                if (chk === true) {
                    alert((this).value);
                    $(this).attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true, 'checked': false, 'aria-selected': false }).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    alert('done');
                    flg = 1;
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $(this).attr({ 'disabled': false, 'aria-disabled': false }).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    flg = 1;
                    return false;

                }
            }

        });
        if (flg == 1)
            return false;
    });


});
```

But it says

> `(this).attr` is not a function

Its applying the attribute

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Please read the jQuery documenation: http://api.jquery.com/each/.

Comment: what is `val`?? It seems it is not working because of undefined variable. check the console in your favorite developer tool for any errors.

Comment: The problem only is its not applying the attributes

Comment: @pavezalam So, there are no errors in console?

Comment: No, there is no error

Comment: and i am doing alert for $(this) just before the line applying attribute it says undefined

Comment: and i am doing alert for (this) just before the line applying attribute it alters correct value

Comment: Not sure why are you running two times `.each` function here. The problem looks to be related to scoping of variables. Anyway, can you post the screenshot of the alert message here? or just write the text in your post above.

Comment: I have 2 list of similar items, i have to disable selected item of first in second list, and in first list i have prefix lstrYM with Item and in second list having prefix ltrY2 with item

Comment: There is no need to compare `chk` variable with `true`. just mention it like this `if (val == val2 && chk) {`. I updated your code. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMGyj/).

Comment: That does not matter, I am able to in the condition , $(this).attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true, 'checked': false, 'aria-selected': false }).addClass('ui-state-disabled'); is not working,

Comment: and i am doing alert for $(this) just before the line applying attribute it says undefined – pavez alam 17 mins ago 
 
and i am doing alert for (this) just before the line applying attribute it alerts correct value –

Answer (score 1):

inside `.each()` callback `this` refers to the dom object which does not have the `.attr()` method - it is provided by jQuery so you need to get the jQuery wrapper for the element so you need to use `$(this).attr()`

```
$('#lsltrY2axis option').each(function () {
    var val2 = this.value;
    alert(val + ";" + val2 + ";" + chk);
    if (val == val2 && chk == true) {
        $(this).attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true, 'checked': false, 'aria-selected': false }).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr({ 'disabled': false, 'aria-disabled': false }).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(this).attr([attribute is here]);
```

using `this` refers to DOM.

Also you must replace all `this` occurrences with `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

I have changed `this` to `$(this)`
then `==` to  `===`
Hope it works

```
$('#lsltrY2axis option').each(function () {
                var val2 = $(this).value;
                alert(val + ";" + val2 + ";" + chk);
                if (val === val2 && chk === true) {
                    $(this).attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true, 'checked': false, 'aria-selected': false }).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).attr({ 'disabled': false, 'aria-disabled': false }).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                }

            });
```

Comment: `chk === true` think about  it. :) and also why `===` instead of `==`?

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
$(this).attr
```